# DataTables - How do I get/set the value of a cell in a row?

Tags: get, set, datatables, row, cell

I´m iterating through the rows of my DataTable with the example I found here in documentation but I want to get the data of the second column, analyze that value and then set my processed value on that cell.

```
tablaProgDetalle.rows().every( function ( rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop ) {
 // I suppose here goes the processing and the setting of the cells values.
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### SOLUTION

You can use [`row().data()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/row%28%29.data%28%29) inside the anonymous function to get and set row's data. Please note that variable `this` in inside the anonymous function refers to row being iterated.

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

table.rows().every( function ( rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop ) {
    var data = this.data();        

    data[0] = '* ' + data[0];

    this.data(data);
});
```

#### DEMO

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/986capby/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: Thank you very much ... so simple, yet needed you to point it out ... greetings from Peru

Answer (score 0):

You can use rowID to do this; we can set rowID in rowCreated: callback of Datatable, or manually while inserting rows upon table creation. Here I am incrementing 3rd column value upon some event in my project.

```
//DOM only addition
var rowID = your rowID goes here; 

var cols = Table.row(rowID).data();

var count = parseInt(cols[2]);
count = count + 1
cols[2] = count.toString();
Table.row(rowID).data(cols);
```